# Grails 3.2.4 Spring Security 3.1.1 http 302 on login page assets

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, spring-security

upgrading from Grails 2.5.1 to Grails 3.2.4, spring-security-core:3.1.1

application.groovy

```
`grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = "InterceptUrlMap"
grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
        [pattern: '/', access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/error', access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/index', access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/index.gsp', access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/shutdown', access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/assets/**', access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/**/js/**', access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/**/css/**', access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/**/images/**', access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/**/favicon.ico', access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/login', access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/login/**', access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/logout', access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/logout/**', access: ['permitAll']]
]`
```

No annotations or requestMap configurations in the project.

login/auth.gsp
`<meta name='layout' content='main'/>`

assets are in `assets/images
                    /javascripts
                    /stylesheets`

I'm using the spring security plugin's LoginController, LogoutController, and login.auth.gsp.

The rendering of the assets (css, js, and images) of the login/auth.gsp page is being redirected to the login/auth.gsp page, images are broken. I'm working with IntelliJ 2016.3.4, but running from CMD has the same result. Any idea?

Comment: Did you try to "permitAll" for "/**" pattern just to check if your config is applied at all?

Comment: I tried the same thing in my play "bookstore" app, and it works. The 2.5.1 security implementation is convoluted, mixing annotation, static, and requestmap. Decided to start a new conversion project without any security. Get the project running first, then introduce security bit by bit: static first, then replace with requestmap, then mix requestmap authorization with LDAP authentication.